# Undefined method or local variable with active merchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I have the following class method in my Product model that calculates total price within the basket:

```
def self.total_basket_price(basket)
    where(id: basket.to_a).sum(:price)
end
```

And i have this within my view:

```
<%= number_to_currency(Product.total_basket_price(basket)) %>
```

Both work as expected until i try to implement a purchase method in my Order model:

```
def purchase
response = GATEWAY.purchase(Product.total_basket_price(basket), credit_card, purchase_options)                                   
end
```

It throws out an `undefined local variable or method` on the `(basket)` above.

I can't see why the `basket` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this error, well, because there is no method or local variable `basket` in your model. So, either:

a) Define a method that returns the basket object:

```
def basket
  # some logic here to return basket.
end
```

b) Pass in the basket to your method:

```
def purchase(basket)
  response = GATEWAY.purchase(Product.total_basket_price(basket), credit_card, purchase_options)                                   
end
```

c) Or, if you are working within an instance of `Basket`, pass in the instance as `self` instead of `basket`.

```
  response = GATEWAY.purchase(Product.total_basket_price(self), credit_card, purchase_options)
```